# Variable's value changing unexpectedly : Java/Android Studio

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am making an app on Android studio, which records sound using the mic and simultaneously converts it to decibel values on another thread. I need to stop the process when the stopRecord function is called, and hence I want to stop the thread in the stopRecord function. I am using a static class variable for this, whose value I set to "1" when stopRecord is called. By default, the value of the variable is "0", in which case the thread must continue to run in a loop. However, the variable's value always sets to "1" unexpectedly even before the Run method of the runnable is called, which is evident if you run the file and see the Log.i . As a result, the loop in the run() of the runnable is not even entered, and the runnable runs only once.
I seriously don't know why the value is changing, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
package com.example.rohanbs.soundtest;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView mStatusView;

    private static double mEMA = 0.0;
    static final private double EMA_FILTER = 0.6;

    static String decider="0";
    private dbRunnable newdb = new dbRunnable();
    MediaRecorder recorder;

    class dbRunnable implements Runnable{

        @Override
        public void run(){
            Log.i("Runnable","called");  //Log to see if runnable is called successfully
            Log.i("decider",decider);   //decider is supposed to be "0" until stopRecord is called, but somehow becomes "1" before that 
            while(true){
                Log.i("Runnable","called");
                if(decider=="1"){
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }


    public void startRecord(View view) {
        Log.i("Inside", "start record");
        if (recorder == null) {
            recorder = new MediaRecorder();
            recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            recorder.setOutputFile("/dev/null");
            try {
                recorder.prepare();
            } catch (java.io.IOException ioe) {
                android.util.Log.e("[Monkey]", "IOException: " +
                        android.util.Log.getStackTraceString(ioe));

            } catch (java.lang.SecurityException e) {
                android.util.Log.e("[Monkey]", "SecurityException: " +
                        android.util.Log.getStackTraceString(e));
            }
            try {
                recorder.start();
                Thread dec1 = new Thread(newdb);   //Creating new thread
                dec1.start();                      //Starting the runnable

            } catch (java.lang.SecurityException e) {
                android.util.Log.e("[Monkey]", "SecurityException: " +
                        android.util.Log.getStackTraceString(e));
            }
        }
    }
    public void stopRecord(View view){
        if (recorder != null) {
            recorder.stop();
            recorder.release();
            recorder = null;
        }

        decider="1";

        Log.i("Hello","record complete");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void updateTv(){
        mStatusView.setText(Double.toString((getAmplitudeEMA())) + " dB");
    }
    public double soundDb(double ampl){
        return  20 * Math.log10(getAmplitudeEMA() / ampl);
    }
    public double getAmplitude() {
        if (recorder != null)
            return  (recorder.getMaxAmplitude());
        else
            return 0;

    }
    public double getAmplitudeEMA() {
        double amp =  getAmplitude();
        mEMA = EMA_FILTER * amp + (1.0 - EMA_FILTER) * mEMA;
        return mEMA/100;
    }

    // Used to load the 'native-lib' library on application startup.
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
    }
}
```

Comment: A) hint: study Java **basics** before going for such advanced stuff. You really should **know** that you should not use == to compare objects, but calling the `equals()` method! B) I would also advise to *not* use a string like that, but a boolean with a nice name, like `private volatile keepLooping` and C) read about `volatile`

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a boolean call "recording" instead of the string. Set it to false once called...etc. You only call `stopRecord()` on the button click? Where else do you set the decider value?

Comment: I've already tried using a boolean value, and also int; all of them give the same problem. I call stopRecord() only on button click, no where else.

Comment: If you start with the boolean at false, then when you start recording you set it to true, when you press stopRecord() the boolean doesn't change? I know it is not set to 1. Try removing the static in your declaration.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell of your code, you set the variable *once* to "0" and never reset it. So if you were to start, stop, and start again, the value would never be "0" again. A simple fix is to ensure you are always resetting this variable before starting a new recording:

```
recorder.start();
decider = "0"; // Reset control variable before starting thread
Thread dec1 = new Thread(newdb);   //Creating new thread
dec1.start();
```

Your logic to break the while loop is wrong, btw.

```
if (decider == "1") {
    break;
}
```

In Java `==` means reference equality, so this will almost certainly be `false` always. Do `"1".equals(decider)` instead (notice the order to avoid a `NullPointerException`).

Hope that helps!